# Вырезать часть текста из строки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть строка, в которой содержится текст типа:

`<p>заголовок</p>
 <p>содержание</p>
 <p>еще что-то</p>`

Вопрос: Каким образом мне вырезать только **содержание**? оно всегда идет вторым тегом `<p></p>`

То есть, мне нужно из этой строки сделать строку вида:

`<p>заголовок</p>
 <p>еще что-то</p>`

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Текст и тег неизменные, всегда `<p>содержание</p>`?

Comment: тег неизменный всегда. текст всегда разный в этом теге

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/^.*?<\/p>.*?\K<p>.*?<\/p>/is','',$str);
```

Расшифровка выражения:

```
^           # Начало строки
.*?         # любые символы
<\/p>       # конец первого тега P
.*?         # любые символы
\K          # точка начала совпадения (замены)
<p>.*?<\/p> # вырезаемые символы в теге
/is         # флаги выражения, без учета регистра, однострочное (. включает перевод каретки)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourStr);
$p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(1);

var_dump($p->textContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать с помощью регулярных выражений.

```
$output=preg_replace("/<\/p>[^<]*<p>[^>]*<\/p>/", "</p>", $input_lines);
```

Онлайн тест:  http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jkS

Comment: Дело в том, что во втором теге `<p></p>` не всегда один и тот же текст. точнее сказать он всегда разный там. единственное что постоянно, это то что этот текст обернут в тег `<p>` и то что этот тег всегда идет вторым, например: `<p>блабла</p> <p>это вырезать</p> <p>текст какой-то</p>`

Comment: @Денис Понял, отредактировал ответ